# Displaying page construction guides

Tags: margins, book-design, overlays

Is there any way to overlay some lines and dimensions on the document so that one can see where the margins end and more easily examine the overall layout and ratios of elements on the page?

See for example, some of the illustrations of frameworks in this article on the [canons of page construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canons_of_page_construction) and this one on [margins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_%28typography%29) (which displays dimensions).

Comment: Do you want to have the page layout measurements to overlaid with your document content (as opposed to a mock-up page with layout figures on them)? Only on a pre-specified page? If measurements are not that important to be displayed with the "lines", then `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` would suffice.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Just to add another **useful** package that does it:

```
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
```

(as many people load `geometry` anyways, it is a nice gadget)

Answer (score 54):

Use `\layout` form the `layout` package. This produces:

[image]

and prints the layout details on the bottom:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}\layout
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 44):

If you just want the boundaries overlaid on the actual pages, independently of other packages,

```
\usepackage{showframe}
```

Comment: Nice sub-package of `eso-pic`, a pity it has no documentation...