# What do headheight, headsep, etc. do in the vmargin package?

Tags: header-footer, margins

In the vmargin package, the `\setmarginsrb` command sets margins, among other things, with this syntax:

```
\setmarginsrb{left margin}{top margin}{right margin}{bottom margin}%
{headheight}{headsep}{footheight}{footskip}
```

The first four parameter set the width of the left margin, etc.  What do parameters `headheight`, `headsep`, `footheight`, and `footskip` do?  I gather that they have something to do with placement of headers and footers, but I'm having trouble finding documentation that explains this clearly.  The vmargin documentation doesn't make it very clear, and I'd like to understand what I'm doing rather than experimenting until it looks right.

Feel free to send me to another question or an external a page that provides a good explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying page construction guides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/displaying-page-construction-guides)

Comment: @Werner I think this question is related to the one you linked to, but it's not really a duplicate. The question here is about four specific dimensions and not about the general page layout.

Comment: Right, I agree @GonzaloMedina, it's not a duplicate, as my comments to your answer indicate.  The standard diagrams that are referenced in the other question's answers don't explain enough.

Comment: Don't use `vmargin`: it's incompatible with packages such as `ateveryshi` that's used by `eso-pic` or others that try to place things in the background of a page. I think that `geometry` is much easier for setting the page parameters.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An image is worth a thousand words:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}

\layout

\end{document}
```

[image]

- `\headheight` is the height od the area reserved to typeset headers.
- `\headsep` is the vertical length between the header and the top of the text area.
- `\footskip` is the vertical length between the bottom of the text area and the bottom of the area reserved for footers.
- `\footheight` is a command not used anymore in LaTeX2e; it's there just for compatibility reasons. The `vmargin` documentation says about `\footheight`:

> LaTeX2e (unless in compatibility mode) does not know `\footheight` any
>   more. `vmargin` does not set this variable if it does not exist, and
>   sets it if it does. As `\footheight` was not used by LaTeX 2.09 all
>   this has little significance.

In the standard classes, the top of the text is at a distance of `\voffset+1in+\topmargin+\headsep+\headheight` from the upper border of the physical page (by dafault, `\voffset=0pt`).

I've never used the `vmargin` package. If you want to customize the page layout, popular packages are [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and [`typearea`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/typearea). The documentation for `geometry` contains also useful explanations on the lengths used in the desaign of page layout.

Comment: Sorry about commenting too fast, Gonzalo.  I've deleted my first comment as it's no longer appropriate.  OK, I'm still a little confused.  What's the relationship between `\headheight` and `\topmargin`?  Does the text start `\headsep` + `\headheight` + `\topmargin`below the top of the paper?

Comment: @Mars in the standard classes, the top of the text is at a distance of `\voofset+1in+\topmargin+\headsep+\headheight` from the upper border of the physical page (by dafault, `\voffset=0pt`).

Comment: @Mars I added my last comment to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo.  The `\layout` diagram makes sense now.  And I just looked at the `geometry` documentation and tried it for the first time.  You're right--the diagrams are very clear, and I now have a simpler solution for dealing with my grant application's 1-inch margins requirement.

Comment: @Mars You're welcome. Glad to hear the problem's been solved.

Comment: The diagram, which appear in (for example) memoir class docs, is not enough. For example: `\headsep` is from bottom of header to top of text. By bottom, does that mean lowest descender of actial text there, or of the font? By top, does that mean tallest ascender of actual text there, or 1em above baseline, or what? Same confusion for footer. This is not trivial. Without proper care, and setting some mysterious TeX internals not mentioned above, it is difficult to get an exact baseline grid on facing pages of a book.