# Fancyheader cfoot overlaps with main content

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, longtabu

UPDATED question. Here is an MWE - finally I could produce one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{magyar}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\globFooter}{
    \def\alignFooter##1{\vtop{\null\hbox{##1}}}
    \cfoot{%
    \begin{tiny}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \alignFooter{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{rBdytQH.png}}
    &
    \alignFooter{\begin{tabular}{lll}
    Address line 1     Address line 1 & Telephone 1     Telephone 1  & Web 1 Web 1 Web 1 Web 1 \\
    Address line 2 & Fax line    &    skype text\\
    Address line 3    &    Mobile line    &    Web 2
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{tiny}
    }
}


\geometry{tmargin=1in,bmargin=2.5in,lmargin=0.7in,rmargin=0.7in}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\globFooter

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]

Here is some more text that will position the last rows of the table near the footer: Nulla euismod, dolor vitae faucibus tincidunt, ante sem commodo massa, vitae maximus ante nisi eget magna. 

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {@{}X[p,l]ccrlrrc@{}} %
                              \multicolumn{6}{p{12cm}}{First row in the table} \\
                            \multicolumn{3}{l}{}
                            & \small 1.0 &  egy.  99\,999 & 99\,999 HUF &                \\
                        \multicolumn{6}{p{12cm}}{Second row in the table} \\
                        \multicolumn{3}{l}{}%
                        & 1.0 &   alk.  &                 5\,000 & 9\,999 HUF & \\
            \end{longtabu}

\end{enumerate}


\bigskip

\bigskip

\end{document}
```

It does not work without the image. The image is here:

[image]

It seems that the problem is related to the `longtabu`, because the footer overlaps with the `longtabu` when the bottom of the table is close to the end of the page. Here is the example overlap:

[image]

Comment: May be you have to adjust the bottom margin. May be you have to adjust the `\footskip`. How do we know? We don't have the full code :(

Comment: Shouldn't cfoot automatically resize the footer to fit the contents? Also I don't understand how it is related to the margins. I just tried, and the same problem can be reproduced with different margin settings (also with different paper sizes). Just I have to add / remove some rows to the table to make it appear. One thing is sure: it is NEVER bad if I put plain text into the document. Already tried with many pages of lorem lipsum. It is clearly related to the longtabu plus the cfoot together.

Comment: Finally I could produce a MWE

Comment: I was experimenting some more, and it seems that adding an invisible (zero point high) horizontal rule to the top of the cfoot solves the problem: `\cfoot{\rule{0.5\textwidth}{0pt}` but I don't understand why!

Comment: Add `,includefoot,footskip=0.1in` to `\geometry{tmargin=1in,bmargin=2.5in,lmargin=0.7in,rmargin=0.7in,includefoot,footskip=0.1in,showframe}`. `showframe` is just for demo. Remove it.

Comment: `! Package xkeyval Error: `foo‌​tskip' undefined in families `Gm'.`

Comment: `\cfoot...` does not (cannot??) adjust the margins automatically. In the case of headers, it will adjust them, although too late to avoid inconsistency. Hence, it issues a warning in that case. But footers are different, I think.

Comment: @cfr: Are you saying  that the footer is rendered on the margin? I thought that the footer is ABOVE the margin.

Comment: By default, yes. The footer and header are included in the margin. `includehead` or `includefoot` etc. change that. See page 3 of geometry's manual.

Comment: @harnish-kumar: Please post "includefoot" and possibly "includehead" as a soltion. By adding that one thing to my document, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Oh, I see now! cfoot does not calculate the height of the footer at all. I have to set it manually. Is that right?

Comment: @nagylzs: Only `headheight` and `footskip` are adjusted automatically. But this will result in inconsistent page layout. So it is better we adjust them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the header and the footer are not included in the text body. But you can include them using `includefoot` and `includehead` keys of `geometry` package. In this case you have to adjust the `footskip` also. We make `footskip` = `25pt`, otherwise a warning is issued. The solution is

```
\geometry{tmargin=1in,bmargin=2.5in,lmargin=0.7in,rmargin=0.7in,includefoot,footskip=25pt,showframe}
```

`showframe` is just for demo and should be removed in actual document. If you have headers, try adding `includehead` also and adjust the headheight`(and possibly`headsep`). Watch out for warnings, for, any incorrect settings would be notified.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{magyar}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\globFooter}{%
    \def\alignFooter##1{\vtop{\null\hbox{##1}}}
    \cfoot{%
    \begin{tiny}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \alignFooter{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
    &
    \alignFooter{\begin{tabular}{lll}
    Address line 1     Address line 1 & Telephone 1     Telephone 1  & Web 1 Web 1 Web 1 Web 1 \\
    Address line 2 & Fax line    &    skype text\\
    Address line 3    &    Mobile line    &    Web 2
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{tiny}
    }
}


\geometry{tmargin=1in,bmargin=2.5in,lmargin=0.7in,rmargin=0.7in,includefoot,footskip=25pt,showframe}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\globFooter

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]

Here is some more text that will position the last rows of the table near the footer: Nulla euismod, dolor vitae faucibus tincidunt, ante sem commodo massa, vitae maximus ante nisi eget magna.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {@{}X[p,l]ccrlrrc@{}} %
                              \multicolumn{6}{p{12cm}}{First row in the table} \\
                            \multicolumn{3}{l}{}
                            & \small 1.0 &  egy.  99\,999 & 99\,999 HUF &                \\
                        \multicolumn{6}{p{12cm}}{Second row in the table} \\
                        \multicolumn{3}{l}{}%
                        & 1.0 &   alk.  &                 5\,000 & 9\,999 HUF & \\
            \end{longtabu}

\end{enumerate}


\bigskip

\bigskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also found this figure that explains margings, footers headers and how they are related. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132170/what-do-headheight-headsep-etc-do-in-the-vmargin-package

Comment: I'm still confused. If we use `includefoot` then the footer becomes part of the text body, and the footer will be above the margin. In that case, what is the meaning of footskip? It is supposed to be "the vertical length between the bottom of the text area and the bottom of the area reserved for footers". But if we include the footer into the text area, then there is no such thing as "area reserved for footers below the text area". Then what does it mean? :-(

Comment: @nagylzs: There is area reserved for footer. But the text height is inclusive of that.

Comment: @HarishKumar By the way, this is going on in chat right now :-)