# Showing frame boundaries in memoir document

Tags: memoir

The package showframe.sty seems not to play nicely with memoir.cls. A minimum example where the displayed main frame box doesn't coincide with the position of the main body text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\textwidth = 12.2cm
\textheight = 19.8cm
\oddsidemargin = 1.95 cm
\evensidemargin = 1.95 cm
\topmargin = 2.1cm

\usepackage{blindtext,showframe} 
\begin{document}

\Blindtext
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

(Things only get worse with the frames for headers not matching custom-designed headers, etc.)

All I want to be able to do is to show (for editing purposes) the frame surrounding the main body text on a page. Indeed, all I *really* need is to be able to show the location of the bottom of the main textbox. Any easy way of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide an MWE with the textbox you would like to 'highlight'?

Comment: I just mean showing the boundaries of the box containing the main body of the text. Nothng fancy!

Comment: The document `\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext,showframe}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}` does not show any problems with the interplay between `memoir` and `showframe`. So it is difficult to answer your question as long as it is unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Example now given -- use memoir to do memoir-ish things with non-default settings for page layout and it seems things go wrong with showframe

Comment: Okay, +1 for the MWE. Try `\usepackage[showframe, pass]{geometry}` and see if it achieves your goal

Comment: Thanks that seems to work fine! (I hadn't twigged that you could use geometry in a memoir.cls document). Thanks!

Comment: @PeterSmith Since it works for you, I've posted it as an answer. Please consider marking it as accepted if you are satisfied with it. `:-)`

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42329/8666

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the `showframe` option from the `geometry` package instead. If you're using `memoir`'s options to configure your page margins, then you need to pass the option `pass` when loading `geometry` to prevent it from messing up your margin settings. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\textwidth = 12.2cm
\textheight = 19.8cm
\oddsidemargin = 1.95 cm
\evensidemargin = 1.95 cm
\topmargin = 2.1cm

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\Blindtext
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: geometry showframe option]

---

**Minor Edit:**

Due to the discussion in the comments, I've decided to input the problem which I *believe* OP is facing. (The 'conflict' between `memoir` and `showframe` packages).

[image: wrong showframe..]

Comment: Memoir has own way to determine page layout, so use geometry is not special advantage. To see page layout, in preamble just add package, `showframe`: `\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}`

Comment: @Zarko According to OP, the `showframe` package was not working fine for him, so I suggested a separate solution with the `geometry` package. I'm not too sure why the `showframe` package doesn't work though, if you have a way to make the `showframe` package work as OP's intended, please feel free to post a separate answer :) p.s. OP changed his margins.

Comment: If the claim of OP is true, than he has problem with some other package than memoir. This is worth to investigate. I so far, regardless that i very frequently use memoir, didn't experienced such a case.

Comment: @Zarko Have you tried using OP's code? I don't get the frames surrounding the text using the `showframe` package as I do with geometry's showframe option. And I'm pretty sure my `memoir` package is updated, as is my distribution etc.

Comment: I test OP MWE. Frame normally show up.

Comment: @Zarko Interesting. The edit I made above was tested purely with OP's code as well. I'm not too sure where's the problem then..

Comment: The geometry trick works for me, using showframe with the minimal example produces the unwanted result Troy shows. (I've found that by tweaking the geometry package just a bit, you can also remove the unwanted extra vertical line  and the unwanted extra horizontal line at the bottom -- but that's just aesthetics.)