# show margins in latex document

Tags: margins, styles

Let's say we would like to heed the margins when writing a submission such as using https://www.dagstuhl.de/en/publications/lipics
Now I remember there was an option that makes the margins visible, so one knows immediately where the document overflows. Searching the net though did not turn up anything, but I remember there was one such option. I'd appreciate if someone reminds me how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean using something like `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`? If so, probably a duplicate of [this.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/displaying-page-construction-guides)

Comment: Or use the `showframe` package. Also, passing option `draft` to `\documentclass` shows black rectangles next to overfull lines.

Comment: @frougon, `[draft]` works, I see -- it shows black lines exactly at "bad" places.